# Achieving polymorphism with sorting functor

Tags: c++, comparator, functor

I'm trying to achieve something similar to using a comparator in Java. I want to be able to hold a sorting strategy in an object as an instance variable, which I can give to list.sort()

My current attempt (that isn't working):

```
struct strategy {
    virtual bool compare(const int* pro1, const int* pro2) = 0;
    bool operator()(const int* pro1, const int* pro2) {
        return compare(pro1, pro2);
    };
};

struct myComp : public strategy{

    bool compare(const int* pro1, const int* pro2) {
        return *pro1 > *pro2;
    }
};

int main() {
    strategy * s = new myComp();

    list<int *> l;
    int a1 = 1;
    int a2 = 2;
    l.push_front(&a1);
    l.push_front(&a2);

    l.sort((*s));

    for (list<int*>::iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it)
        cout << **it << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Presumably because... when I use myComp directly, I just use the actual class name myComp, but I want to use an actual instance. Is there any simple way to do what I'm trying?

Alternatively, I wouldn't mind using a function pointer, but I want my code to be object-oriented, so I want to avoid having non-member functions that just hang in the air.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: strategy* s = new myComp();

Comment: you're right, I was changing names around to make it clearer, thanks

Comment: I think it's unnecessary to have the comparators in an inheritance hierarchy; this idea probably comes from the Comparator interface in Java. (@Beyeler said as much, too.) It's sufficient if the argument is "callable" and returns a bool. There is no polymorphism to be gained from an inheritance hierarchy unless you link the comparator inheritance to the argument inheritance hierarchy, e.g. by making comparators resp. comparison functions part of the type held in the list. (Which would mean you cannot hold `int`s any longer.)

Comment: What I want is to have an object that can receive information from the outside regarding how it will sort its internal list. I kinda agree that this might not be necessary, initially I wanted to use a function pointer, but it's not an object oriented design to have functions outside of a class to designate sorting strategies

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that `std::list::sort` takes a copy of type `strategy` (see the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/)) which results in slicing. The answer to this would be: don't mix templated function calls and virtual inheritance. Two comparators that compare the same type don't have to be related in this approach and if they are you still need to specify the implementing class, not the base class.

In your case replace

```
strategy * s = new myComp();
...
l.sort((*s));
```

with

```
...
l.sort(myComp());
```

For the sake of performance, instead of providing a virtual function that compares per item you should think about what system is doing the sort and instead implement the virtual call on that system:

```
class SystemBase {
protected:
    ...
    virtual void Prepare(std::list<int>& list) const = 0;
};
```

or delegate:

```
class System {
public:
     class SystemOperator {
     public:
          virtual void Prepare(std::list<int>& list) = 0;
          virtual void Compute(std::list<int>& list) = 0;
     };

     void SetOperator(std::unique_ptr<SystemOperator> op) { m_operator = std::move(op); }

private:
     std::unique_ptr<SystemOperator> m_operator;
};
```

Comment: @Chum-ChumScarecrows I argue against your statement